# Double Integral of an absolute value

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this double integral, where $p>2$.
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{|x-y|^p}dxdy,
$$
I do like this
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{|x-y|^p}dx = \left. \frac{1}{(1-p)|x-y|^{p-1}} \right|_{-\infty}^0=\frac{1}{(1-p)|y|^{p-1}}
$$
or I have to consider the cases where $x>y$ and $x<y$? If the answer is yes, how do a change the limits of integration?

Comment: $=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx\mathrm dy}{(x+y)^p}$

Comment: You are on the right track. $x<0<y.$ But replace your $(1-p)$ by $p-1$ and beware it must be $>0$ for your first integral to converge.

Answer (score 0):

The double integral you provided is
$$
\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{|x-y|^p}dxdy.
$$

Let's first consider the absolute value function in the integrand. Since $y > 0$ and $x < 0$, we know that $x - y < 0$. Therefore, we can rewrite the integral without the absolute value:

$$
\int_0^\infty\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{1}{(y-x)^p}dxdy.
$$

Now let's perform the integration with respect to $x$. To do this, we will make the following substitution:

$$
u = y - x \Rightarrow x = y - u.
$$

The differentials are related as follows:

$$
dx = -du.
$$

Now we need to change the limits of integration. When $x = 0$, we have $u = y$. When $x = -\infty$, we have $u \to \infty$. Now we can write the integral as

$$
\int_0^\infty\int_{y}^{\infty} \frac{1}{u^p}(-du)dy.
$$

Notice that the integral is now over positive values of $u$. We can now proceed with the integration:

$$
\int_0^\infty\left[-\frac{1}{(p-1)u^{p-1}}\right]_y^\infty dy.
$$

Now we can evaluate the integral with respect to $u$:

$$
\int_0^\infty\left[-\frac{1}{(p-1)y^{p-1}} + \frac{1}{(p-1)\infty^{p-1}}\right] dy = \int_0^\infty\frac{1}{(1-p)y^{p-1}}dy.
$$

To finish, integrate with respect to $y$:

$$
\left[-\frac{1}{(2-p)y^{p-2}}\right]_0^\infty = \frac{1}{(p-2)(p-1)},
$$

provided that $p > 2$. So, the final result is:

$$
\frac{1}{(p-2)(p-1)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! But, in the last substituition, why doesnt explode when you evaluate on 0?

Comment: The substitution $u=-x$ is useless. OP's direct first integral calculation (once corrected) works as well.

Comment: Yes, I get the same after correction. But, why doesnt diverge when he evaluates on 0?